# Javascript/jQuery addClass/removeClass for translation of container not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a slide that can move slide ways. If I press left button I want my  to move left(the content have width of 358.8%, so more the that shows in screen). However, the jQuery code that I wrote is not working how I wanted to do. Please Help!!!!!!!

```
**HTML CODE**

    <body>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="content">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageRight">
                    <div class="ContentTextLeft">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageLeft">
                    <div class="ContentTextRight">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageRight">
                    <div class="ContentTextLeft">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageRight">
                    <div class="ContentTextLeft">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageLeft">
                    <div class="ContentTextRight">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <img src="https://t1.kakaocdn.net/kakaocorp/operating/co/main-content/3254.png" class="contentImageRight">
                    <div class="ContentTextLeft">
                        HAHAHA
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery CODE**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#arrow-right").click(function(){
              $( "slideshow-container" ).removeClass( "onePosition" );
              $( "slideshow-container" ).addClass( "twoPosition" );
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#arrow-left").click(function(){
              $( ".content" ).removeClass( ".twoPosition" );
              $( ".content" ).addClass( ".onePosition" );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**CSS CODE for two/onePosition**

```
  <style>
  .onePosition{
      transform: translate(5%);
      transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  .twoPosition{
      transform: translate(-90%);
      transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  </style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6iLL.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. none of your tags have either 'onePosition' or 'twoPosition' as classes
2. Your logic should all be under ONE documentReady event there's no need for multiple declarations for that same eventListener.
3. If this is your approach please provide your CSS rules as they seem to be the ones doing the heavy lifting, which is possible with transformations

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've just edited the post and added image to show more details.

Comment: add '.' before your class selectors on 'slideshow-container' **edit: checkout the changes**

Comment: Also you might want to have an indicator for the slide that is currently being shown, If you're calling a class then the changes will be applied to all the elements that fall under that class